# Angular Faq Is Contradicting on Service and Storing Primitive Data

Tags: angularjs

From Angular.js documentation, it states:

https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq

> Of course, global state sucks and you should use $rootScope sparingly,
>   like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language.
>   In particular, don't use it for code, only data. If you're tempted to
>   put a function on $rootScope, it's almost always better to put it in a
>   service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily
>   tested.
>
> Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to
>   store and return bits of data.

I have always been told to store primitive data in a service to keep a controller from being bloated. In addition, angular has `angular.module("app").value()` to store data. So why would they say `don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data`?

Answer (score 1):

The `value` and `constant` in Angular is for constant, static data that isn't changing.  So, that is what you'd store there.  If it's something that is dynamic but needs to be accessible in multiple areas, use a `service` or `factory`.

Their sentence is a bit ambiguous, but I think they mean, don't do this:

```
function MyService () {

   this.appTitle = "My App Title";

}
```

and then inject it everywhere you need to know the app title.  There are better ways to accomplish something like this.

Of course it always depends on your scenario.

Comment: I am under the impression `constant` is meant changed in `.config()` and `value` does not have to be a static. Also, both of these are factories from what I have been told.